# How to disable warnings in tensorflow written to output when using the c api of tensorflow

Tags: c, tensorflow, c-api

I use TensorFlow 1.13.1 by integrating it using the C-API (my program is in C++). Tensor flow writes a warning to the std output, and I want to suppress this warning as I a need the std output and std error under my control, not wanting tensorflow to write on it. How can I suppress it?

I already tried to set the environment variable TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL='3' but this seems not to work in TensorFlow 1.13.1 (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26348) But the solution in the link seems not to work for C API

Hope someone can give me a hint on how I could solve this.

Comment: This is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066248/tensorflow-c-api-logging-setting